# JSF EL overload method inheritance

Tags: java, jsf, el

Consider following scenario:

My Java classes:

```
public abstract class AbstractListBaseModel {
    public void onColumnToggle(ToggleEvent event) {
        // toggle column
    }
}

@Named
public class MyListModel extends AbstractListBaseModel {
    @Override
    public void onColumnToggle(ToggleEvent event) {
        // toggle column...
        super.onColumnToggle(event);
        // ...and do some more
    }
}
```

myList.xhtml:

```
<p:commandButton id="myToggler" .../>
<p:columnToggler trigger="myToggler" datasource="myListData">
    <p:ajax event="toggle" listener="#{myListModel.onColumnToggle}"/>
</p:columnToggler>
```

My application always calls the MyListModel.onColumnToggle() method and that is wha I want - but is this the guaranteed behavior?
[What You Can Not Do in EL](https://www.baeldung.com/intro-to-jsf-expression-language#CanNotDo) mentions that EL doesn't support overloading.

And IntelliJ IDE shows both method declarations when moving the cursor over the listener!

Comment: That are two different things. Overriding is not overloading. What you experience is expected and correct.